# Convert WEBM to HEVC with alpha

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to convert a simple WEBM video with transparency to HEVC with alpha. I couldn't find any resources about how to convert without losing the alpha channel.

I don't know if it's possible with FFMPEG:

> encoding requests cannot be made here as FFmpeg does not contain a native hevc encoder.

cf. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7965

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### VideoToolbox supports alpha / transparency

FFmpeg does not have its own HEVC/H.265 encoder. It supports 7 HEVC/H.265 external encoders (most are hardware based) including libx265 which does not currently support alpha.

As of now **only the VideoToolbox HEVC Encoder** (`-c:v hevc_videotoolbox`) **supports alpha**. This is a hardware accelerated encoder for Apple hardware. This has been updated after FFmpeg 4.3 was released, so you'll have to use a build from the current git branch, or wait for 4.4.

Example command adapted from the relevant [commit](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2021-March/126705.html):

```
ffmpeg -i input%03d.png -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 output.mov
```

The "HEVC Video with Alpha" profile will only be used when the `-alpha_quality` value is not 0 (default is 0, range 0-1.). See `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox` for more info.

**This answer may become outdated due to continuous developments, so make sure to research the current situation.**

### Checking if an encoder supports alpha / transparency

```
$ ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265
Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p yuv422p yuvj422p yuv444p yuvj444p gbrp yuv420p10le yuv422p10le yuv444p10le gbrp10le yuv420p12le yuv422p12le yuv444p12le gbrp12le gray gray10le gray12le
```

If it supported alpha it would have pixel format with an `a` in the name, such as `yuva420p` or `rgba`. As you can see libx265 does not yet support alpha.

### Related bug reports to watch

- [#7965 - Support for HEVC decoding with Alpha](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7965)
- [#9088 - HEVC bitstream with alpha layer to mp4](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9088)

Comment: So it's impossible to do that, at least with FFMPEG?

Comment: would you know an alternative solution?

Comment: @BastienRobert Stick with VP9 (webm) for alpha, or investigate other HEVC encoders.

Comment: @BastienRobert Looks like [Apple's Compressor can do it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202204).

Comment: looks like it's impossible to import webm into compressor

Comment: @BastienRobert Maybe it will accept QuickTime Animation (RLE) video: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v qtrle output.mov`

Comment: Very extensive answer! Could not get it encoding until this info, thanks!

Comment: I tried this solution, copied exactly what the poster said, but the alpha channel was missing. I'm noticing that the "HEVC Video with Alpha" profile is also missing.

Comment: Is there an HEVC encoder that supports alpha on linux? Where would I look for that?

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69262399/4433326

Answer (score 4):

This is my example how to convert transparent VP9 `webm` video to `mov`. Instead of `libvpx` better to use a new `libvpx-vp9` (the more advanced version of libvpx).

Step 1. Split webm video to frames

```bash
ffmpeg -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm -pix_fmt rgba image_%04d.png
```

Step 2. Combine all frames to a new `mov` video.

```bash
ffmpeg -i image_%04d.png -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 output.mov
```

Now you can use it on web

```html
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
    <source src="output.mov" type="video/quicktime">
    <source src="input.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also racked my brains over this problem but finally got it to work. Here are the steps I did (on a Mac):

1. Convert the transparent webm to a set of transparent pngs (with 25fps) with this command:

   `ffmpeg -vcodec libvpx -i transparent.webm -pix_fmt rgba -r 25 out/image_%d.png`
2. Create a transparent mov video from the pngs:

   ```
   cd out
   ffmpeg -i image_%d.png -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5  -bits_per_mb 8000 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le output.mov
   ```

(taken from: [how can I convert a stack of PNGs with transparency to a video playable with Keynote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777781/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-of-pngs-with-transparency-to-a-video-playable-with-key) )

3. This mov is transparent but has a huge filesize (10gb in my case). Open the video with quicktime, click File > Export as. Select the desired resolution and then select HEVC and keep “Preserve Transparency” checked.