# How can I convert a webm file with alpha channel to a hevc encoded file that will play in safari on an IPad?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, webm, transcoding, hevc

I've got a webm file with transparency : https://itype.techforge.com.au/assets/videos/upshot/module1/NP_1A.webm

I'm trying to convert it into something that will play in the video element of a web page in the Safari browser on an IPad.

An example of a file that works is : https://rotato.netlify.app/alpha-demo/movie-hevc.mov

My attempts at doing this conversion have all failed.  3rd party apps seem to all lose the alpha channel.

On my mac I tried ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 output.mov
```

However, while this resulted in a file that reported a codec of MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265) (hvc1) the resulting file still has a black background instead of a transparent one.

ffmpeg log : https://pastebin.com/DMM9y5PU

Comment: ffmpeg log added.

Comment: You sir, are a straight up genius!  Put this as an answer so I can accept it =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in, default decoder for VP9 currently does not support alpha / transparency. Manually use the decoder *libvpx-vp9*:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 -movflags +faststart output.mov
```

Your ffmpeg needs to be compiled with `--enable-libvpx` for this to work.

Comment: macos compilation instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS

Comment: Unrecognized option 'allow_sw'.   Any suggestion ?