# how can I convert a stack of PNGs with transparency to a video playable with Keynote

Tags: ffmpeg, png

I used to convert a stack of PNGs with alpha transparency using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i frame_%03d.png -vcodec png output.mov
```

I have an old `mov` where this worked. Now I tried to do that again a while later (on an M1 Mac now). Now it doesn't work anymore. Here are the file properties:

| property | old movie (works) | new movie (does not work) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| resolution | 378 × 378 | 1600 × 1000 |
| codec | Apple ProRes 4444 | PNG |
| alpha channel | yes | ? |
| color profile | SD (6-1-6) | ? |
| software | Lavf57.41.100 | Lavf59.16.100 |

The `?` shows that I cannot open the new file in Quicktime, nor import it in Keynote. Any idea how I can use `ffmpeg` to convert my image stack to a file with transparency that works in Keynote / Quicktime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://ottverse.com/ffmpeg-convert-to-apple-prores-422-4444-hq/) and experimenting helped me find a solution:

```
ffmpeg -i frame_%03d.png -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5  -bits_per_mb 8000 -pix_fmt yuva422p10le output.mov
```

The key seems to be the `a` in `yuva444p10le` which enables an alpha channel and to use the profile `4` or `5` (didn't see a difference). Using the encoder `prores` or `prores_aw` also gave no alpha in my experiments.

**Bonus:** on a Mac, a right-click on the resulting file and selecting the video-encoding option opens a dialogue. Using one of the HEVC options and selecting the checkmark to keep transparency brings the file size way down (from 109 MB to 3 MB in my case).